# SAS macro which will apply means and univariate procedure on each year for revenue variable

Tags: sas-macro

Let’s say we have "Revenue" information for different years from 2005 to 2009 with variable revenue. I want to write a sas macro that applies means and univariate procedure on each year for revenue variable. I want some clues how to work around this as am clueless how to proceed. Any help would be appreciable.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've tagged this question with 'sas-macro', this doesn't necessarily need any macro code. In general, any of the PROCs take a BY statement, so you would just run a

```
proc means data=revenue;
  by year;
  ... more statements...
run;
```

Start with a few of the examples from http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146738.htm and see how you get on.